# SQL SELECT dynamic from RDB$RELATION_NAME, to check tables integrity

Tags: sql, firebird

I'm trying to create a stored procedure (or a a trigger, function, anything) to check if all the tables in a database is accessible.

My idea is to get all the tables in database, and then try to acess them with a simple select, if this succeeds for all the tables, everything is supposed to be ok.

I couldn't think of anything else to solve this problem, but I don't know how to do this, or all this intead.

1 - to get all the tables name I did:

```
SELECT RDB$RELATION_NAME TABLE
    FROM RDB$RELATIONS
    WHERE RDB$VIEW_BLR IS NULL 
    AND (RDB$SYSTEM_FLAG IS NULL OR RDB$SYSTEM_FLAG = 0)
    ORDER BY TABLE
```

Now I just need to create the `SELECT` statement to each table, and run a query:

```
SELECT FIRST 1 * FROM [TABLE];
```

while it's ok, it continues, if all the tables are accessible, my database is ok.

Can anybody help me with this? Is this the correct aproach to solve this problem?

Comment: What is the real problem you are trying to solve? Why do you think you need to check if the table is accessible? Firebird is pretty reliable, there is no real need for this.

Comment: Firebird has a tool for this (gfix), which is also available as a service request.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As a_horse_with_no_name commented, this is really strange request... if you see the table in the `RDB$RELATIONS` you can be pretty sure the table exists in the database. If the table is listed in the DB metadata but actually doesn't exist then the DB is corrupted and your idea to use `select` to check it's "accessibilty" is pointless... Also, the table might be there but the user might not have select right for it, IOW you need to take the user rights into account too.

Anyway, you can use the [`EXECUTE STATEMENT`](http://www.firebirdsql.org/file/documentation/reference_manuals/reference_material/html/langrefupd25-psql-execstat.html) to execute dynamically built DSQL statement, something like

```
declare stmt varchar(1024);
declare ctab varchar(31);
BEGIN
  FOR SELECT RDB$RELATION_NAME
      FROM RDB$RELATIONS
      WHERE RDB$VIEW_BLR IS NULL AND (RDB$SYSTEM_FLAG IS NULL OR RDB$SYSTEM_FLAG = 0)
  INTO :ctab DO BEGIN
     stmt = 'select ... from ' || ctab; 
     execute statement stmt;
  END;
END
```

To check is the database corrupted you should use the [`gfix`](http://www.firebirdsql.org/file/documentation/reference_manuals/user_manuals/html/gfix.html) utility with [`-validate`](http://www.firebirdsql.org/file/documentation/reference_manuals/user_manuals/html/gfix-dbverify.html) option.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, as I said before, maybe it´s realy pointless, but I want to garantee that all the tables in the database is acessible, before try to connect to them. If there is another way, I'll be thankfull to know.

Comment: Celso, were you trying to check if the database schema conforms to some version that you expect the DB to be? Like I can see trying to detect if a database has the latest schema version.

Comment: Israel, it'n not about check the version of the schema, it´s about to detect corruption in any table of the schema. I just want to know if all the tables are acessible in the database.

Comment: @CelsoMJunior to check for corruption you should use the gfix utility, I added link to the documentation into my answer.